# React-router typed-url and refresh on tomcat, elastic beanstalk

Tags: reactjs, apache, tomcat, react-router, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

There are a lot of questions about this topic which is that typed URL and refresh do not work when using react on production but I'm trying for a long time now and for some reason it does not work.

I'm using React with Spring boot and tomcat. I am using BrowserRouter for routing. I deploy the application on aws elastic beanstalk. When I deploy, I do the following:
run `npm run build` then copy the resulting files in build folder into webContent folder then export project as war file and deploy it to aws.

As I understood, the main solution for this is to server the index.html file for all requests and I tried the following to do that:
- add the following to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/
  ServerName domain.elasticbeanstalk.com

  AliasMatch ^/(.*)$ /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/index.html

  <Directory "/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.html [L]
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

From the questions I read, it is suggested to use /var/www/html but I did not get why. I tried to use it by copying everything from ROOT to it but also did not work.

I tried many variations to the code I put in the configuration file.

With the configuration, I get the error
`SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`.
On firefox, I get `The script from “http://awsdomain.com/static/js/2.7322c0fb.chunk.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.`

and on chrome I get same error but with css files and not js.

At this point, I assume the serving of index.html is working but there is another issue that the server is trying to parse some js or css files like html or text which would not work. In any case, I have no idea how to tell the browser to parse them in the right way and why is it parsing them with no errors in the normal way (without solving the routing issue)?
I tried to add type attribute to link and script tags in index.html but did not work.

There are many stuff I tired specially in the config files on aws instance but it would be hard to put it all here. I'm hoping from the comments to get the root of the problems and then I can give any missing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is finally fixed.
The following is my final addition to the httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/
  ServerName domain.elasticbeanstalk.com

  <Directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

    DirectoryIndex index.html

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
    </IfModule>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, it was annoying that dir_module was not included by default which is needed by DirectoryIndex. To include it, add `LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so`.